# Need help to configure one windows and one linux server using one static ip?

Tags: windows, linux, ip

I am not sure if it is possible to configure one windows server and one linux server using only on static IP address. [Note:I have two CPU's each of 2GB RAM, One modem-router and one static IP address.]

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for Network Address Translation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation -- google the make/model of your router and the word "NAT".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you want to acchieve and how are you failing?

do you want the servers to talk to each other? both of them to be online? both of them to be reachable from the internet?

if they only need to talk to each other, assign them two different static IPs in the same subnet and connect them via a network cable (possibly via the router)

if you want to have both hosts to be reachable from "outside", you will most likely need NAT and port-forwarding, where one port on the router is forwarded to a specific host in your private network; note that a given port can only be forwarded to one single host at a time, so you cannoth run a webserver with *default* port 80 (which is the port that every webbrowser will use if you specify an ordinary http-URL) on both your linux and your windows server.

Comment: some of my ASP dot net sites are hosted on windows server and other sites are hosted on linux server. Those hosted on windows server are licensed and those on linux server are open source site.

Comment: in this case you would need a proxy (see the other posts); however, i don't think that you will need two separate machines in order to be able to host free+nonfree ASP sites (i'm sure there are a number of linux webservers out there that run closed-source proprietary services as well as windows servers running open source sites)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a reverse proxy, something along these lines:

1. Assume that the Windows web site is named win.example.com and the Linux web site is named lin.example.com.
2. DNS entries for win.example.com and lin.example.com both point to the same static IP address.
3. NAT forward to the Linux box.
4. The Linux box's web server will be configured with name virtual servers for win.example.com and lin.example.com.  lin.example.com will be served directly.  win.example.com will be reverse proxied to the Windows machine.  (How this is done will depend on your web server software).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to get another IP address.

You definitely need to set up NAT somehow, in your firewall or router.

Forward inbound web traffic to either a proxy server such as SQUID http://www.squid-cache.org/

or your apache server, using mod_proxy.

Here's a link to get you started on that. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html